# AWS Load Balancing two instances. One has crashed. Should I duplicate the working one?

Tags: django, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, supervisord

So what had happened, lucky for us, is that one of our instances has crashed. The second one runs perfectly as they are both attached to a load balancer for AWS EC2 instances. Because this is a sensitive server I wanted to pass by what I had in mind to do for some advice.

First, I am thinking about removing the broken instance (instance6) from the load balancer. After doing so I was going to create another instance with the image of the working one (instance5) along with the same security group. Followed by django, nginx and uwsgi installation and a clone. Finally, python manage.py runserver and the usual server set up. 
Ideally, instance5 is working perfectly and I would like for instance6 to work the same way. I have done some reading but feeling not as confident as I hope to be. The developer that works with our instances has left and many of us are not 100% on everything.

EDIT: Am I better off trying to fix instance6? Im trying everything I can with it but the supervisord is not working the same even though the conf files are both similar.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have auto-scaling enabled? How were the servers created originally? If you have auto-scaling you can likely terminate the bad server and a new server will be added. If you don’t have auto-scaling you could just create a AMI from the good server and launch a new one and add it to the ELB.